# Only return collection when field is false

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

I have the following entity in my api-platform:

```
#[ApiResource(
    operations: [
        new Get(),
        new GetCollection(),
    ],
    normalizationContext: ['groups' => ['read']],
)]
#[ApiFilter(
    filterClass: SearchFilter::class,
    properties: [
        "id" => SearchFilterInterface::STRATEGY_EXACT,
        'hash' => SearchFilterInterface::STRATEGY_EXACT,
        'used' => SearchFilterInterface::STRATEGY_EXACT,
    ]
)]
class ResetPasswordHashes
{
    #[ORM\Id, ORM\Column(name: "id"), ORM\GeneratedValue]
    #[Groups(['read'])]
    public int $id;

    #[ORM\Column(name: "hash", length: 255)]
    #[Groups(['read'])]
    public string $hash;

    #[ORM\Column(name: 'used')]
    #[Groups(['read'])]
    public bool $used;

    #[ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity: Contact::class)]
    #[ORM\JoinColumn(name: 'contact_id', referencedColumnName: 'contact_id')]
    #[Groups(['read'])]
    public ?Contact $contact;

    #[ORM\Column(name: "created_at")]
    #[Groups(['read'])]
    public ?\DateTime $createdAt;
```

This is just an excerpt of the relevant lines.  Idealy I only want to return the information when the the $used is false.  Is there a way to set up the entity where I protect the `$contact` information if `$used == false`?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example to protect the `$contact` information if `$used` is false:

```
#[ApiResource(
    operations: [
        new Get(),
        new GetCollection(),
    ],
    normalizationContext: ['groups' => ['read']],
)]
class ResetPasswordHashes
{
    //...
    public bool $used;

    #[Groups(['read'])]
    public ?Contact $contact;

    //...

    #[Serializer\Groups({"read"})]
    public function isUsed(): bool
    {
        return $this->used;
    }
}
```

The `isUsed` method is decorated with the `@Serializer\Groups` annotation, which specifies that it should be included in the "read" group.
Then in your controller you can use the Symfony's serializer component to handle the serialization and apply the isUsed method as a condition for the inclusion of the $contact property:

```
/**
     * @Route("/reset-password-hashes/{id}", name="reset_password_hashes_get", methods={"GET"})
     */
    public function get(ResetPasswordHashes $resetPasswordHashes, SerializerInterface $serializer) 
    {
        $data = $serializer->normalize($resetPasswordHashes, null, [
            'groups' => ['read'],
            'used' => $resetPasswordHashes->isUsed() ? ['contact'] : [],
        ]);

        return new JsonResponse($data);
    }
```

This way the `$contact` property will only be included in the serialization if `$used` is false.

Comment: Ive tried your code and found a number of issues.  First of all its GetCollection not a GET request.  In order to get your code to work I had to remove the exclude line for `\src\Entity` in services.yml to get the autowiring to work, which I have since read is not the correct solution.  Even after I did all that and got it working, it returned`id,used` in the json only.  Which would indicate that its running a get and not a collection.  Not sure how to fix it from here.